# Get text and set range from iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, range

I must change the style of a part of text in an HTML document showed in iframe.

I have a json file in which there are start/end/id of text that should be modified.

My problem is that i can't set text range.

```
 var r = document.createRange();
 var node = document.getElementById("file").contentWindow.document.getElementById("d1e152");
 r.setStart(node, 0);
 r.setEnd(node, 12);
```

**file** is the id of the iframe, while **d1e152** is the id of the paragraph.
It return "TypeError: Argument 1 of Range.setStart is not an object." error in r.setStart() line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like `node` is null. This could be for one of many reasons, but I'd guess you're trying to retrieve the element within the iframe before the iframe has fully loaded, so you'll need to wait using `window.setTimeout()` or an event handler.

Another issue which is not your immediate problem is that it's a good idea to create the range on the iframe's document instead of the main document. According to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-dom-20121206/#interface-range) it shouldn't matter but I've definitely seen issues in older browsers. Can't remember specifics now.

```
var iframeDoc = document.getElementById("file").contentWindow.document;
var r = iframeDoc.createRange();
var node = iframeDoc.getElementById("d1e152");
r.setStart(node, 0);
r.setEnd(node, 12);
```

Comment: It seems to work, but get this `TypeError: Argument 1 of Range.setStart is not an object.`. If i append `.style.color = '#00CC00'` (just for a test) to `iframeDoc.getElementById("d1e152")` it works and text is colored. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Ciotto: There must be something else going on because the error you're seeing can only happen if `node` is null or some other non-object and you'd get an error if you tried to access its `style` property.

Comment: I noticed that sometimes works and sometimes not. I tried this: `var iframedoc = document.getElementById("file").contentWindow.document;
   setTimeout(function(){
    var r = iframedoc.createRange();
    var node = iframedoc.getElementById("d1e152");
    r.setStart(node, 0);
    r.setEnd(node, 5);
 [other.code] , 500);` It only work sometimes also without the `setTimout()` function. Maybe I used it in wrong position? But I'm pretty sure that i run this code only when iframe is loaded because i do some control before this function.

Comment: Ok, before i do it when the document is loaded, now i put this code on a button and i have no problem now. Thanks for your help anyway